# How to use actionbutton as a trigger to conditionalPanel?

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a shiny code that plots graphs with action buttons.

Since I have both R plot and plotly plots, I want to plot them in the same Panel with their buttons are clicked. Here's a simple example:

UI:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
  fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(

        hr(),
        actionButton("button1", label = "Button 1",
                     style='padding:4px; font-size:80%'),

        hr(),
        actionButton("button2", label = "Button 2",
                     style='padding:4px; font-size:80%'),

        width = 2
      ),

      mainPanel(

        wellPanel(

          conditionalPanel(
            condition  = "paneltype == 'A'",
            plotOutput("plot",height = "1820px",width = "1250px")

          ),

          conditionalPanel(
            condition = "paneltype == 'B'",
            plotlyOutput("plot",height = "auto")

          )

        )

      )
    )
  )
)
```

Server:

```
paneltype = 'A'

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$button1, {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot(1:10)
    },width = 1400)
    paneltype <<- 'A'
  })

  observeEvent(input$button2, {
    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
      plot_ly(as.data.frame(1:10))
    })
    paneltype <<- 'B'
  })

})
```

EDIT:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui=shinyUI(
  fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(

        hr(),
        actionButton("button1", label = "Button 1",
                     style='padding:4px; font-size:80%'),

        hr(),
        actionButton("button2", label = "Button 2",
                     style='padding:4px; font-size:80%'),

        width = 2
      ),

      mainPanel(

        wellPanel(


          uiOutput("plots")
        )

      )
    )
  )
)

server=shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$button1, {
    output$plots=renderUI({plotOutput("plot")})
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      layout(matrix(c(1,2,3),3,1,byrow=TRUE))
      plot(1:10)
      plot(10:1)
      plot(20:40)
    },width = 1400)

  })

  observeEvent(input$button2, {
    output$plots=renderUI({plotlyOutput("plotly")})
    output$plotly <- renderPlotly({
      plot_ly(as.data.frame(1:10))
    })
  })

})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

conditionalPanel works on client side(js), so its not see your variable.

Here you can do it on server side using `renderUI`

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui=shinyUI(
  fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(

        hr(),
        actionButton("button1", label = "Button 1",
                     style='padding:4px; font-size:80%'),

        hr(),
        actionButton("button2", label = "Button 2",
                     style='padding:4px; font-size:80%'),

        width = 2
      ),

      mainPanel(

        wellPanel(


          uiOutput("plots")
        )

      )
    )
  )
)

server=shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$button1, {
    output$plots=renderUI({plotOutput("plot")})
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot(1:10)
    },width = 1400)

  })

  observeEvent(input$button2, {
    output$plots=renderUI({plotlyOutput("plotly")})
    output$plotly <- renderPlotly({
      plot_ly(as.data.frame(1:10))
    })
  })

})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

If you want some plot in one you can do it in such way

1) define plot function

```
plot_f=function(){
  graphics::layout(matrix(c(1,2,3),3,1,byrow=TRUE))
  plot(1:10)
  plot(10:1)
  plot(20:40)
}
```

2) renderPlot

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot_f() 


    },width = 1400)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now but I am not sure why but my plot has a layout option (multiple plots), and when I switch between plot and plotly buttons, the layout option doesnt work so that only the last graph is plotted.

Comment: You have to show reproduceble example.. it hard to say without it

Comment: Sorry I edited your comment rather than my post by mistake. So as you can see I tried to use layout but I think it is using plotly to plot it? Thank you very much.

Comment: I am sorry, I think it is because plotly masks `layout` and I need to load plotly in the server in order to use `plotlyOutput`, is there a way to get around it?

Comment: If you want base layout use `graphics::layout()`